# PropertyChanged member for INotifyPropertyChanged is always null

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to bind a text block to my variable `slctItem`. I can see it contain the necessary data I need however my window does not show the data I'm expecting.  Here is the code behind for my control. This control is used by a pop up window which will display the values of the control.

When walking the code I see that handler returns null every time in the `OnPropertyChanged()` method.  Why? I must be doing something wrong here. Again `slcItem`does contain the data I'm wanting to use. The `OnPropertyChanged()` method also fires it just contains null for handler.

```
public partial class MetaData : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _slctItem;

    public MetaData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string slctItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _slctItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _slctItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("slctItem");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    internal void Refresh()
    {
        try
        {
            // If DataContext is Null or a detached DataRow, disable the view
            if (DataContext != null && (DataContext is DataRow && ((DataRow)DataContext).RowState != System.Data.DataRowState.Detached))
            {

                if (DataContext is "Something Here")
                {
                    slctItem = (("Something Here")this.DataContext).NAME;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("MetaData -> Refresh(): " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here is the XAML code for my control. Here I'm trying to bind to `slctItem`

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=slctItem, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource myFirstCharToUpperConverter}}" Width="150" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

Comment: It looks like you never set the `DataContext` property. Is that code just missing or did you forget to write it? The event handler wont set without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `DataContext` to yourself:

```
public MetaData()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

This will allow the binding to find the appropriate property.  Right now, if you look at the `Debug Output` in the Output Window at runtime, you should see binding errors since the data context is unset.

Comment: So I cant do this because I set DataContext on the XAML side like so. If I implement your solution the CREATED_BY is no longer displayed. 

`<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding}" Text="{Binding CREATED_BY, Converter={StaticResource myFirstCharToUpperConverter}}" Width="150" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />` 

However your DataContext makes sense. Im just not sure what to set on the XAML side for slctItem?

Comment: @GET1NE You can use a RelativeSource binding to bind to self.

Comment: So this worked. Thanks for the help!

`<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=slctItem, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource myFirstCharToUpperConverter}}" Width="150" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />`